# "of" versus. "for" for this sentence

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Using the panel on the left side, the user specifies the values **of/for**  the context variables required to match the rule.

When you enter the values of something, you enter value for it, or you enter the value of it?

Comment: It is more proper to say "left-*hand* side", not "left side".

Comment: Also, it's unclear what is *required to match* - variables or values.

Comment: @VictorBazarov it refers to values or the matter that they should have value, I may should say, *specifies the values of context variables, which are required to match the rule*.

Comment: Either preposition is fine. You've asked several questions which are bordering on "proofreading" in the context of your technical "documentation". Personally, I think you'd do better spending some time reading more general advice about how to write clearly and concisely. For example, *...specifies the context variable values that match the rule* or *...specifies context variable values matching the rule* include less irrelevant "padding".

Comment: @FumbleFingers do you know good source for that? I mean book, something..

Comment: A/Any [dictionary.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of) Definition #2 there: *used to indicate derivation, origin, or source*. But to repeat my substantive point, agonizing over what's effectively a stylistic choice of preposition here will not improve the lucidity of your text. But removing excess verbiage might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if those variables already have values, then those values are *of* the variables.  If the variables have indeterminate values to begin with, and the user is supposed to enter something, which will be independently validated, perhaps, then those values are *for* the variables.

So, I vote for *for* in this case.

Comment: Yes the user should provide the values for them.

Comment: On the subject of validation, when a value is given by the user, is there a procedure that verifies whether the value is in the required range or any other criteria?  If so, that value does not become the value *of* the variable until/unless it is accepted.  If that's so, then *for* is better, I think.

Comment: Not actually, there is no emphasis on the validation. We can suppose whatever the user provides is assigned to the variable.

Comment: Then there is no difference, really.